# python3 tkinter scrollbar problemas a inserir

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

bom dia,

Eu estava a criar uma interface gráfica com python e para isso usei o tkinter e estava a tentar criar uma scrollbar dentro do meu projeto porem ele nao reconhece o comando para conectar a scroolbar as label's existentes(segue o exemplo):

```
from tkinter import *

class JanelaPrincipal(Frame):
        def __init__(self,master):
                Frame.__init__(self,master)
                self.master.title('Avocado')
                self.master.geometry('800x600')
                self.configure(height=200,width=200)
                #scroll bar
                self.scroll=Scrollbar(master)
                self.scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="y")
                self.batata=Label(self.master,width="800",height="10",text="Algum texto",relief="raise",yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
                self.batata.pack(expand=0, fill=BOTH, side=TOP)

root=Tk()
app=JanelaPrincipal(root)
root.mainloop()
```

O erro que retorna é:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pap.py", line 16, in <module>
    app=JanelaPrincipal(root)
  File "pap.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.batata=Label(self.master,width="800",height="10",text="Algum texto",relief="raise",yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-yscrollcommand"
```

Já pesquisei bastante porem todos usam aquele argumento e quando tento usar o interpretador da erro, se alguem poder ajudar agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que você está tentando criar uma scroll em um `Label` e essa classe não tem a opção `yscrollcommand`.

Você pode utilizar essa propriedade em `Listbox`, `Canvas` etc.

Veja um exemplo de utilização dela com a classe `Text`, utilizando seu código como base:

```
from tkinter import *

class JanelaPrincipal(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master.title('Avocado')
        self.master.geometry('800x600')
        self.configure(height=200,width=200)
        #scroll bar
        self.scroll=Scrollbar(master)
        self.scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="y")
        self.batata=Text(self.master,width=800,height=10,relief="raise",yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.batata.insert(END, "Algum texto")
        self.batata.pack(expand=0, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

root=Tk()
app=JanelaPrincipal(root)
root.mainloop()
```